# Как с помощью регулярного выражения вывести последние 2-3 цифры траспортного номера как регион?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Я делаю задачу, где необходимо проверить валидность транспортного номера с помощью регулярных выражений. Валидный транспортным номером (1 буква, 3 цифры, 2 буквы, 2-3 цифры).Я написала код:

```
import re
car_id = input("Введите номер: ")
result = re.findall(r'^([АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]\d{3}[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2})(\d{2,3})$'', car_id)
if car_id is not None:
    print(f"Результат: Номер {car_id} валиден. Регион: {car_id}")
else:
    print(f"Результат: Номер {car_id} не валиден")
```

Код срабатывает так и выдает следующий результат, что неверно по условиям задачи т.к в начале 1 буква:

```
Результат: Номер AF222hv193 валиден. Регион: AF222hv193
```

Но мне нужно чтобы в ответе после региона выходили последние 2-3 цифры. Как это сделать?

Comment: У вас вопрос в заголовке на совпадает с вопросом в тексте.

Comment: Номер, который Вы проверяете, невалидный (как минимум, в нём 2 буквы перед первыми цифрами).

Comment: @Эникейщик если я укажу в заголовке, как вывести последние 2 цифры, с вашей точки зрения - это будет корректно?

Comment: @nomnoms12 по условиям задачи он некорректный, но код так срабатывает и значит, где-то есть ошибка в регулярном.

Comment: @Alina Ясно. Просто меня смутила формулировка _"код работает"_. Рад, что помог Вам)

Comment: @nomnoms12 спасибо вам) Я отредактирую вопрос, чтобы формулировка была более корректной)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

regexp = re.compile(r'^[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]\d{3}[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2}(?P<reg>\d{2,3})$')
car_id = 'А123ВЕ456'

match = regexp.match(car_id)
if match:
    print(f"Результат: Номер {car_id} валиден. Регион: {match['reg']}")
else:
    print(f"Результат: Номер {car_id} не валиден")
```

***stdout:***

```html
Результат: Номер А123ВЕ456 валиден. Регион: 456
```

Comment: спасибо, я только изменила car_id = 'номер' на car_id = input("Введите номер").